# Macros applicable on one column can be applicable to all column in excel VB

Tags: vba, excel

I have excel sheet prepared as a data entry sheet called “INPUT SHEET”. Data is added in various columns against fixed certain no. of rows of this “INPUT SHEET”. 
At the end of each row I have provided one macro button which picks the value from each column and creates another new sheet.

The problem is that I have 100 such columns and I want to avoid editing each macro to work against each column. I want a single macro which identifies column against which the button is pressed and accordingly works on that column only.
Sample macro for COLUMN U is as below: I want a little modification in this sheet so that same code can be applicable to all coulmns.

```
' Macro1 Macro===ROW U
'
   ' Create new sheet copying from DATASHEET 1 before last sheet
    '
    Worksheets("DATASHEET 1").Copy before:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    Sheets("INPUT").Select
    Range("U10").Select
    Selection.Copy
     ' Retaining the name of sheet
    '
   Range("U150").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
     wks.Name = Range("U10").Value
              ' Copying the notes
      '
    Worksheets(Range("u10").Value).Activate
     Range("D62:BF87").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
   Range("AY6").Value = "2"
 Range("A7:BF7").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INPUT!R[3]C[20]"
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

j = 61
For i = 63 To 88
Sheets("INPUT").Select
If Cells(i, 21).Value = "YES" Then
j = j + 1
Worksheets(Range("U10").Value).Activate
Range(Cells(j, 4), Cells(j, 58)).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
Selection.UnMerge
Sheets("INPUT").Select
Cells(i, 2).Copy
Worksheets(Range("U10").Value).Activate
Cells(j, 4).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
Range(Cells(j, 4), Cells(j, 58)).Select
With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Merge
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the column name?

Comment: Please don't use [macros] for MS Office or VBA. [macros tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having 100 buttons, I would probably work with just one, and move it according to the selected cell. That way each time the cursor moves, the button moves and you could then use the `activecell.column` method to sum that column.

The code you could use would be something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)


ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").Left = Cells(40, ActiveCell.Column).Left
End Sub
```

In the sheet of the workbook you are working on. The button in row 40 will move to the selected column.

Comment: I am sorry I could not get your answer fully. I understand that I should create one button (with one macro assigned to it) and copy paste same button (with same macro) at the end of each column.

I can modify the my current code using active.cell method but what I want to know is code for “if a button is placed in a cell “A7” then the action to be taken against column “A” only”. For e.g
Range("A1:A6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

I want the above similar action to be taken against column B if button is placed in cell “B7”.

Comment: Hi Abhimat. Unfortunately, it's not really possible to do it in that way, without using co-ordinates (which is a nightmare, especially if column sizes may change) - as such I have suggested that you instead have one button that works for all columns and moves to each as you select them. Its a different approach to the same thing, but instead of having 100 objects - you have one, which serves all columns.

Comment: Hi Trum, Thanks for the way forward. I would try to work on the approach provided by you.